# Non-POSIX sockets for C

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Are there any non-POSIX sockets for C?

I'm a newbie Linux C programmer and don't need any portability, and I've heard POSIX libraries are just "C wrappers" that someday could cease to exist, perhaps with the new C11 standard.

Also, POSIX sockets are basically BSD sockets.

Although `sys/sockets.h` works fine, are there any *standard C* sockets?

Comment: No, the C standard has no notion of sockets.

Comment: Have a look into the recent [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html). And do not listen to hear-say. Note: yes there are standard sockets: [POSIX (IEEE Std 1003.1)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). As the current edition is from 2013, I would presume it is younger than C11 actually.

Comment: POSIX libraries won't cease to exist; they exist to ensure the compatibility of POSIX-compliant source code across platforms. The might be rewritten atop some other standard -- if some other standard exists.  Or the code for the other standard might be written atop the POSIX sockets.  Or both (POSIX and standard but non-POSIX) might be written atop some third socket interface (also non-POSIX).  But there isn't an alternative standard to the POSIX sockets, which are closely based on the BSD sockets.  Learn the POSIX sockets; you'll use them.

Comment: I would think that the C standard and the POSIX standard are distinct.

Comment: POSIX "cease to exist"?  That's a good one, albeit about 2 1/2 months late.

Comment: The Posix libraries are not "just C wrappers".  "sys/sockets,h" is the "standard" library for C sockets programming (with the possible exception of [Winsock/Winsock2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Windows).  The sockets interface is derived from BSD sockets.  The ISO C programming language standard and the POSIX IEEE 1003.1 standard are two completely different things, by completely different organizations.

Comment: Incidentally, the 'new' C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011, aka C11, which is about 4 years old now) does not define any sockets library.  It does define threading as part of the standard C library (via the `<threads.h>` header), as did C++11 and as does C++14 as part of the standard C++ library (via the `<thread>`, `<mutex>`, `<condition_variable>`, `<future>` headers), but that's about it.

Comment: Learn and use POSIX sockets. Learn and use POSIX everything.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart For some specific programs, I prefer non-POSIX functions. For example, when perfomance is really important, `fopen`, `fread` and `fwrite` over POSIX `open`, `read` and `write` (because of buffering).

Comment: @algolejos: what makes you think [`fopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) is not a part of POSIX? Or 
[`fread()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) or [`fwrite()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwrite.html)?  You have a choice with POSIX.  There are numerous occasions when file descriptors are easier to manage than file pointers; there are certainly times when using file pointers is easier than using file descriptors.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler is the _C Standard Input and Output Library_ (ISO C) a POSIX library?!
C'mon, be gentle with your answer, please.

Comment: @algolejos: Yes.  The POSIX standard includes the standard C library complete (I don't know of any exceptions).  Occasionally it extends the standard library (`scanf()` and `printf()`, for example), and it provides a lot of other functions as well, but it includes the standard C library as a core part of the POSIX library.

Comment: @algolejos: If you follow the links such as [`fopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) which I gave before, you'll see that they're marked: _The functionality described on this reference page is aligned with the ISO C standard. Any conflict between the requirements described here and the ISO C standard is unintentional. This volume of POSIX.1-2008 defers to the ISO C standard._

Answer (score 2):

On Linux and other Unixen, POSIX *is* the native level for many APIs, and for the exceptions (e.g. `readdir` vs `getdents`) the wrapper is usually much easier to use and is as cheap as it can be.

Everything is different on Windows, which is missing a lot of essential features that are present on all other systems, so POSIX calls often must be emulated there. If you have any choice, you'll go into a branch of the industry that doesn't rely on Windows at all.